Returning different widget from data
Hello can someone help me with this. I am trying to return 2 different widget from db. When i do that they look all the same. Example: Listview builder i do return different UI for each data?


Edit your question and add your code, because your question is not clear.

Hello sorry, basicly i am returning listview.builder here from data and i want to change only the last entry's text color and font size. basicly think "Cute Cats" title with 42 font size and others with 26. inside listview builder or another way.

Do you mean you want your Listview.builder show like the image that you have provided?

Yes and rest of with  different design

inside the builder in ListView.builder you have an index parameter, you can check if(index == 0) return a custom widget and pass the model that you have to it, else return different widget.
